# In Elm-Lang what does the \_ -> statement (symbol, operator, pattern) mean?

Tags: elm

I came across what I thought was a pattern in [test code](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-css/blob/master/tests/Tests.elm).
At first glanced it looked to me like a pattern I had never seen before, but what exactly is it?

I am adding this entry for folks who may run into same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in fact ***not a pattern***, but a ***lambda*** (anonymous function, a function definition that is not bound to an identifier.) as pointed out to me by megapctr at [elm slack group](https://elmlang.slack.com/messages/beginners/).

I found this lambda in this [context](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-css/blob/master/tests/Tests.elm):

```
unstyledDiv : Test
unstyledDiv =
    let
        input =
            Fixtures.unstyledDiv

        output =
            ""
    in
        describe "unstyled div"
            [ test "pretty prints nothing, because the stylesheet had no properties." <|
                \_ ->
                    prettyPrint input
                        |> Expect.equal (output)
            ]
```

So to better understand how this lambda works in this context.  I used the elm-repl to write my lambda    (\_ -> "helloWorld").

```
(\_ -> "helloWorld") 5
(\_ -> "helloWorld") 4.0
(\_ -> "helloWorld") "abalone"
(\_ -> "helloWorld") not
(\_ -> "helloWorld") abs
```

output: **"helloworld" ：String**

All producing the same output:　**"helloworld" ：String** for any type input, **Int**, **Float**, **String**, **Function**.

Then to mock the same format as the test code I used piped, <|, the lambda to the identity function, which should result in same output: **"helloworld"**

```
identity <| (\_ -> "helloWorld") "anything"
```

output: **"helloworld" ：String**

To take a step closer to test code snippet I did the following

```
(identity <| (\_ -> "helloworld" ) "anything") |> String.reverse
```

which outputs: **"dlrowolleh" : String**

I hope this helps folks who may be bewildered when seeing code snippets like this for the first time.

## Another Similar Example

### \( ) -> statement

**No Argument/"No Named Argument Native Type" Lambda**

**lambda which takes no argument:**   \() -> "hellouniverse"

```
(\() -> "hellouniverse") ()
```

output: **"hellouniverse" : String**

```
(identity <| (\() -> "helloworld" ) ()) |> String.reverse
```

output: **"esrevinuolleh" : String**

If you try to pass an argument other than **()**, unit, such as **String**, **Int** or **Float**, or **Function** it will result in a compiler error.

***Errors like the following***:

*Example of passing an **Int**, 5*

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================

-- TYPE MISMATCH --------------------------------------------- repl-temp-000.elm

The argument to this function is causing a mismatch.

4|    \() -> "hellouniverse" ) 5
                               ^
This function is expecting the argument to be:

    ()

But it is:

    number
```

*Example of passing a **Function**, identity*

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================

-- TYPE MISMATCH --------------------------------------------- repl-temp-000.elm

The argument to this function is causing a mismatch.

4|    \() -> "hellouniverse" ) identity
                               ^^^^^^^^
This function is expecting the argument to be:

    ()

But it is:

    a -> a
```

Demonstrate use of **No Arg lambda**:

Define test as the following:

```
test x = 
   ((++) "super  "  <|  ( (\() -> "hellouniverse" ) <| x )) |>  String.reverse
```

then to apply function just pass the unit symbol, ():

```
test ()
```

output: **"esrevinuolleh  repus" : String**

Comment: If you want to answer your own questions on SO you can. There is a checkbox for that (Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style). It would have avoided that someone else answered while you were writing your own answer.

Comment: While insightful, the format of this answer does not really fit within SO guidelines. The trial-and-error examples may have a better fit in [Stack Overflow Elm Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/elm/topics). @Acid Burn's succinct and complete answer are a better format for SO.

Comment: Thanks Zimm and Chad

Answer (score 9):

`\_ ->` is an anonymous function that takes one argument, but it does not use the argument in the function body, so instead of naming it like `\a ->` is just discards the argument using `_`.

Comment: Hi Acid, thanks for the response.  I already had the answer, thanks to **megapctr** at [elm slack group(https://elmlang.slack.com/messages/beginners/) was just posting for general audience.

Comment: Sorry, did mean to waste your time!

Comment: I meant did not mean to waste your time!